# Datagrid foreground colour not working

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, header, foreground

I have a simple datagrid that display bidimensional data.
I have tried it in a test project and the result is nice.

[image]

Here is the xmal:

```
<Grid >
<DataGrid Name="dg" Margin="50" FontSize="26" CellEditEnding="dg_CellEditEnding" BeginningEdit="dg_BeginningEdit"  LoadingRow="DataGrid_LoadingRow" EnableRowVirtualization="False"  AutoGeneratingColumn="dg_AutoGeneratingColumn"/>
</Grid>
```

and the relevant event code:

```
 private void DataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
  e.Row.Header = "R" + ((e.Row.GetIndex()) + 1).ToString();
}

private void dg_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
  string str = e.PropertyName;
  int num = int.Parse(e.PropertyName);
  e.Column.Header = "C" + (num + 1).ToString();

}
```

then I have to put it in my real project which is a styled window.

So I put the same very easy xaml (adding background and foreground fore here I have a gradient background) so that the xamls is:

```
<Grid >
<DataGrid Name="dtgNests" Margin="50" FontSize="26" Background="White" Foreground="Black" HeadersVisibility="All" CellEditEnding=" dg_CellEditEnding" BeginningEdit="dg_BeginningEdit"  LoadingRow="DataGrid_LoadingRow" EnableRowVirtualization="False"  AutoGeneratingColumn="dg_AutoGeneratingColumn"/>
</Grid>
```

and the effect is:

[image]

so in short the FOREGROUND is not being set in any part. That is:

- cells
- row headers
- column headers

so nowhere.
Can anyone tell me why?
thank you in advance
Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a WPF DataGrid, all cell-related design needs to be set as the Column's `ElementStyle`, which overrides the foreground set in your Grid. Try the following:

**In your XAML resources:**

```
<Style x:Key="BlackCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
</Style>
```

**In your `AutoGeneratingColumn` handler:**

```
private void dg_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
  string str = e.PropertyName;
  int num = int.Parse(e.PropertyName);
  e.Column.Header = "C" + (num + 1).ToString();
  e.Column.ElementStyle = FindResource("BlackCellStyle") as Style;
}
```

This will apply the foreground directly to your cells