# CellEditEnding not working

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, cell, edit

I have a datagrid on which I want to control the value entered to be numeric.

[image]

So when I enter a wrong value as in the picture

[image]

I want to restore the previous value.

To do that I need to catch the NEW ENTERED VALUE but when I do that

[image]

you can see that I still get the old value before editing.
So what have i got to do to get the NEW entered value which has to be analyzed after the ENTER KEY is pressed?

Comment: If you will use `ObservableCollection<YourClass>` as `DataGrid` `ItemsSource` with bindings to `YourClass` properties, you can get new value in property setter just before it changes.

Comment: Since this is the consequence to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35060738/datagrid-foreground-colour-not-working I am forced to use a datatable from the result of the function private DataView ConvertFromMatrixToDataTable(string[,] matrix)

Comment: maybe it is better to check whether the value is `integer` and allow to input if it is `integer`?

Comment: Datatable or collection it doesn't metter, on CellEditEnding we always get current value. can you give us your datagrid code @Patrick?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CellEditingTemplate` like :

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus" Background="Aquamarine" Text="{Binding Age, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And handle `LostFocus` event of the `TextBox`.

Below code will reject all non-integer values and revert back to original value.

```
private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
            int result;
            if (!int.TryParse(tb.Text, out result))
                tb.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateTarget();
        }
```