# ListView background colour not working

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, background

I have a simple listView put inside other elements.
Since I want to simulate an explorer style I have done that:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvAllowedPPtab2" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="12" Background="{x:Null}"  BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="5" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
              <ListView.ItemsPanel >
                <ItemsPanelTemplate >
                  <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="250" Background="{x:Null}"  VerticalAlignment="Top"></WrapPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
              </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            </ListView>
```

the problem is that by doing that the background gets coloured while i want it to be transparent = null.

[image]

By looking at that

> [Datagrid foreground colour not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35060738/datagrid-foreground-colour-not-working)

as a workaround i've searched for something similar but didn't find any similar event.

Don't know if posting my complete xaml helps
Thanks for helping

--ADD--
At request I post a wider part of my xaml:

```
 <TabItem Name="tabItem2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="80" MouseLeftButtonUp="TabItem_MouseLeftButtonUp"  FontSize="{StaticResource TOOLTIP_FONTSIZE}" IsSelected="false" >
    <TabItem.Header>
      <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="&#xF0F7;" FontSize="{StaticResource TAB_FONTSIZE}"/>
        <TextBlock Name="tbTab2" Visibility="Hidden" FontSize="{StaticResource BUTTON_FONTSIZE}" />
      </StackPanel>
    </TabItem.Header>
    <TabItem.Background>
      <ImageBrush/>
    </TabItem.Background>
    <Grid >
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Border x:Name="Border1Tab2" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="5" Width="200" Margin="10,10,10,10" >
        <StackPanel Margin="-1.8,-0.8,2.2,1.4">
          <ListBox x:Name="lbxPalletsTab2" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Height="600" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" Margin="12,10.2,8.4,10.4" />
        </StackPanel>
      </Border>
      <Border x:Name="Border2Tab2" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" MinWidth="150" BorderThickness="5" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,10,10,10">
        <Grid >
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300px"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

          <Grid  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="50px"/>
              <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Name="tbkPPtab2" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="22" Background="{x:Null}" FontWeight="Black" Text="---" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></TextBlock>
            <ListView x:Name="lvAllowedPPtab2" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="12" Background="{x:Null}"  BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="5" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="ListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
              <ListView.ItemsPanel >
                <ItemsPanelTemplate >
                  <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="250" Background="{x:Null}"  VerticalAlignment="Top"></WrapPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
              </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            </ListView>

          </Grid>
          <Border  Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Gainsboro"  BorderThickness="5" Margin="10,60,10,10">
            <Grid Name="grdPalletTab2" AllowDrop="True" Drop="Grid_Drop"/>
          </Border>
        </Grid>
      </Border>
    </Grid>
  </TabItem>
```

--ADD--
the same problems happens everywhere in my xaml. Even just adding a empty listview with a transparent or null background makes it darkblue. I think I can't override the presets of my styled winwdow.

--ADD2--- as Sivasubramanian suggested here is the relevant part of my style sheet

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource BackgroundDepth4}"/>
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource BackgroundDepth4}"/>
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TextDepth1}"/>
<Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
<Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
<Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
<Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
<Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
<Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
      <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
        <ScrollViewer Focusable="false" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}">
          <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
      </Border>
      <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
          <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledOpacity}"/>
        </Trigger>

      </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

and

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
<Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
<Setter Property="Padding" Value="4"/>
<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
<Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
<Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
      <Grid x:Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="Auto" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
              <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2">
                <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                  <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
              </VisualTransition>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
              <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverElement">
                  <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
              <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd">
                  <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource DisabledOpacity}"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
          </VisualStateGroup>
          <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
              <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedElement">
                  <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
              <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedElement">
                  <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.5"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
          </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Rectangle x:Name="SelectedElement" Fill="{DynamicResource CannoliAccentColorBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Stroke="{x:Null}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" StrokeThickness="0" Opacity="0"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="MouseOverElement" Fill="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Stroke="{DynamicResource CannoliAccentColorBrush}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" StrokeThickness="2" Opacity="0"/>
        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
      </Grid>
      <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource WindowTitleForegroundColorBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
      </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: Have you tried using Transparent instead of x:null?

Comment: Yes just tried now, not working but thanx.

Comment: Could you show the full xaml then, could be a parent item that has improper background set.

Comment: Null is been applied to your listview. your code works fine. But there is something behind your listview that has some color applied which you are seeing in the view.

Comment: Fine I'll post a wider part of my xaml since it's very large. Hope it's enought otherwise i'll post more. In any case it's part of a styled application (not my work) but there should be the possibility of override any default shoundn't it?

Comment: Try to use Snoop and you will find in seconds an element this dark blue color.

Comment: @Patrick is that happened when you selecting item from in listview?

Comment: @Sivasubramanian thanks for testing my code but that's not the case. Even adding a simple listview with   <ListView Background="Transparent"></ListView>  makes it with a darkblue background

Comment: @Ilan sorry I have not understood what you are asking. But if it helps please read my previous comment.

Comment: @Patrick Hi, I've took your code and created my own window. all is working well. Is this behavior is happened when you selecting an item in your ListView? If not try to find some default style in your application that do the Background changes of your ListView.

Comment: @Patrick did you try adding the simple listview in a fresh project??

Comment: @Sivasubramanian yes I did and the listView gets normal. Only when I add to my style project it gets dark. But as I said, there shoud be a way to ovverride style, shouldn't there?

Comment: Please search your xaml style collections and try to find any style with target type ListView, ListBox, Selector or ItemsControl is available without a key set. But i am not sure, I suspect there is something behind the listview has the imagebrush or background color applied.

Comment: OK so listView appears on in my MainView.xaml as for the listBox style I have found a relevant part and deleted background line but that didn't change. Please take a look at it in my add thank you a million.